# This proof implies the interval must be open?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $J\subset \mathbb{R}$. I've been trying to show that $J$ is an interval if and only if $a<x<b$, $a,b\in J$ implies $x\in J$.

If $J$ is an interval this is trivial. The other way around I've supposed first that $J$ is bounded, since the other cases are analogous. In that case, there are $\alpha= \inf J$ and $\beta = \sup J$. By definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$ it is clear that $J\subset (\alpha,\beta)$. On the other hand, if $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$, in that case since $\alpha < x$, we have that that $x$ is not a lower bound for $J$, so there must be $a\in J$ with $\alpha \leq a < x$ and analogously since $x <\beta$, we have that $x$ is not an upper bound for $J$, so there must be $b\in J$ with $x < b$.

In that case, $a<x<b$ with $a,b\in J$. By hypothesis then, $x\in J$ and so $J = (\alpha,\beta)$.

In that case, if $J$ is a set satisfying this property, it implies it is an **open** interval really? Or it could be closed and I've missed something?

Comment: Does interval include unbound "intervals" like $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: No, you don't have that $J\subset (\alpha,\beta)$. Hint: $\alpha$ can be in $J$.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have that $J\subset (\alpha,\beta)$. $\alpha$ can be in $J$. So can $\beta$. The definition only has that $(\alpha,\beta)\subseteq J\subseteq [\alpha,\beta]$

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAndrews. I've really missed that, the infimum and supremum could be there. Anyway, even with this $J$ is an interval, with the difference that now it can be both open, closed or closed on just one of the sides right? Thanks again!